# Circle ceases to be a circle when radius is below a certain value

Tags: unity, mathematics

I'm using the LineRenderer component to draw a circle. It renders fine, but it's a little too large. The smallest I can set the radius is .06f. If I try to set the radius to anything less than that, such as .05f, it ceases to become a circle and resembles more of an oblong shape instead. I posted a couple of pictures below, as well as the full script that I'm using. You can attach this script to your own gameObject and test it out for yourself. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

radius is at .06f
[image: radius is at .06f]

radius is at .05f
[image: radius is at .05f]

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class Circle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer _line;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _radius;

    private void Start()
    {
        _line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        DrawCircle(_radius);
    }

    public void DrawCircle(float radius)
    {
        var segments = 360;

        _line.useWorldSpace = false;
        _line.startWidth = .03f;
        _line.endWidth = .03f;
        _line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        var pointCount = segments + 1; // add extra point to make startpoint and endpoint the same to close the circle
        var points = new Vector3[pointCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
        {
            var rad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * (i * 360 / segments);
            var x = Mathf.Sin(rad) * radius;
            var z = Mathf.Cos(rad) * radius;
            points[i] = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        }

        _line.SetPositions(points);

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * 90);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you find the threshold radius changes in any way when you reduce the number of points/segments in your circle?

Comment: By "threshold radius" I mean the radius at which the problem occurs. Does the circle behave any better at small sizes if there are fewer segments (ie. so the points are spaced less densely)?

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you. That solves the problem. I reduced the value of the 'segments' variable and now I'm able to reduce the radius to below .06 without any problems. Just one thing: is there a formula for what the value of 'segments' should be? I just arbitrarily set it to 130 and the problem went away.

Comment: Not sure! Want to experiment with a few values and post your findings as an answer?

Comment: @DMGregory Well, maybe you can tell me what exactly segments are and why they're relevant? Before, I thought that the more segments you have, the better. Obviously that's not the case. I'm also not sure why the tutorial that I copied the code from originally had the value set to 360. You seem smarter than I am, so any input you can throw my way would be more than appreciated.

Comment: "segments" here is really the number of points you're giving your LineRenderer to draw. Having more segments / more points lets you represent smooth curves more precisely. With fewer segments, you'll approximate the curve more coarsely. It looks like when points are too close together, it confuses the LineRenderer's mesh generation, so by spacing them out more (by increasing the radius or decreasing the number of segments around the circle), you avoid confusing it in this way.

Comment: @DMGregory Wow, thank you. I'll experiment with the value and see if there's a formula between the radius and the number of segments. Also, feel free to convert your comment to answer so that I may accept it.